# Find a point on a curve given the tangent line $y=-x$

Tags: calculus

"Given the equation $2y^3+6(x^2)y-12(x^2)+6y=1$" (and it's implicit derivative I did $(4x-2xy)/(x^2+y^2+1)$) find a point given the line $y=-x$.

I know how I would do this if it was just $y=$, but I have been having trouble given the equation.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out myself.
You set $(4x−2xy)/(x2+y2+1)$ equal to negative one (as expected). 
Next since you know y=-x, you substitute y with -x.
After simplifying you get x=$-1/2$.
Plug it into the original equation and you get y=$1/2$, which satisfies both equations.
So the point P is ($-1/2$,$1/2$).